# Azure AD B2C Tenant ID Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I don't even know where to begin. I am a Windows Forms C# developer. I am trying to learn Azure. I am following a tutorial here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

I have checked and rechecked my steps. I can successfully log in to the app. I can see the claims displayed when I click the claims button. As soon I click the To-Do List button, my app crashes in `TaskController.cs` `Index` method. It crashes on trying to obtain an `AuthenticationResult`.

```
// GET: Makes a call to the API and retrieves the list of tasks
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
            var scope = new string[] { Globals.ReadTasksScope };

            //string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };

            var app = publicClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(Globals.ClientId)
                        .WithB2CAuthority(Globals.B2CAuthority)
                        .Build();

            // IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
            //            var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
            //AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();

            //var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync(Globals.SignUpSignInPolicyId);

            //var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync(Globals.SignUpSignInPolicyId);
            //AuthenticationResult ar = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scope)
            //                                           .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            //                                           .ExecuteAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result;

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync(Globals.SignUpSignInPolicyId);

                // Try to acquire an access token from the cache. If an interaction is required, MsalUiRequiredException will be thrown.
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                            .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                // Acquiring an access token interactively. MSAL will cache it so you can use AcquireTokenSilent on future calls.
                result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scope)
                            .ExecuteAsync();
            }

            //var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync(Globals.SignUpSignInPolicyId);

            // var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            //AuthenticationResult ar;
            //try
            //{
            //    ar = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            //                .ExecuteAsync();
            //}
            //catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            //{
            //    ar = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            //                .ExecuteAsync();
            //}

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

            // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Handle the response
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JArray tasks = JArray.Parse(responseString);
                    ViewBag.Tasks = tasks;
                    return View();

                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    return ErrorAction("Please sign in again. " + response.ReasonPhrase);

                default:
                    return ErrorAction("Error. Status code = " + response.StatusCode + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            /*
                If the tokens have expired or become invalid for any reason, ask the user to sign in again.
                Another cause of this exception is when you restart the app using InMemory cache.
                It will get wiped out while the user will be authenticated still because of their cookies, requiring the TokenCache to be initialized again
                through the sign in flow.
            */
            return new RedirectResult("/Account/SignUpSignIn?redirectUrl=/Tasks");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ErrorAction("Error reading to do list: " + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

As you see, I have commented out several attempts to get this to work. At the end of the tutorial, it says:

> Known Issues
> MSAL cache needs a TenantId along with the user's ObjectId to function. It retrieves these two from the claims returned in the id_token. As TenantId is not guaranteed to be present in id_tokens issued by B2C unless the steps listed in this document, if you are following the workarounds listed in the doc and tenantId claim (tid) is available in the user's token, then please change the code in ClaimsPrincipalsExtension.cs GetB2CMsalAccountId() to let MSAL pick this from the claims instead.

I have noticed that in the app variable in my code, the `TenantID` property is null. I followed the work-arounds listed in the document, and still no `TenantID`.

Here are the steps listed in the document: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#acquiring-a-token-to-apply-a-policy

I followed all steps, not just from the bookmarked location and below.

Here is what I am seeing when I debug:

Here is what I am seeing from app:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice the `UserTokenCache.NullPreferredUsernameDisplayLabel` says:

> Missing from the token response

It talks about that in the known issues mentioned above.

Now the accounts variable has the following:

[image]

The result variable stays null and execution goes to the catch block where it tries again to get a result using `AcquireTokenInteractive(scope)`. This also fails and execution moves to the final catch block at the bottom of the method.

The error message states:

> ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

That doesn't make sense to me. I think the problem starts with the fact that the app variable is not acquiring the `TenantID`. But I do not know what to do about it.

I noticed a couple of things missing from the tutorial. It did not say to grant Admin privileges to the scope and API permissions, but I did that.

[image]

[image]

Here is my web.config from the TaskWebApp project:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <!--MSAL cache needs a tenantId along with the user's objectId to function. It retrieves these two from the claims returned in the id_token. 
        As tenantId is not guaranteed to be present in id_tokens issued by B2C unless the steps listed in this 
        document (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#caching-with-b2c-in-msalnet). 
        If you are following the workarounds listed in the doc and tenantId claim (tid) is available in the user's token, then please change the 
        code in <ClaimsPrincipalsExtension.cs GetB2CMsalAccountId()> to let MSAL pick this from the claims instead -->
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="db1b052a-415c-4604-887c-e27b59860001" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="975f1457-e3e2-4cb8-b069-6b0b6b46611d" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="Gw4.3o-DRDr.j_828H-JMfsk_Jd1d-jQ5p" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.b2clogin.com/tfp/{0}/{1}" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44316/" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signupsignin1" />
    <add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_1_edit_profile" />
    <add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="B2C_1_reset" />
    <add key="api:TaskServiceUrl" value="https://localhost:44332/" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ApiIdentifier" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com/demoapi/" />
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
  </appSettings>
```

And my TaskService `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="1c8e9aee-d04a-4fb1-aa32-8ba808122e76" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signupsignin1" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
  </appSettings>
```

Please let me know how I can go about troubleshooting this. Out of everything I have tried, app always ends up with a null `TenantID`.

Have also tried this that ends up with null `TenantID`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet#acquire-a-token-interactively

See below:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {"user.read"};
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).Build();
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result;

try
{
     result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                       .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch(MsalUiRequiredException)
{
     result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                       .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be mapping web app to AAD. Please check these steps once, hope it helps you:
Null Tenant Id will come during the mapping the web app to Azure active directory (B2B/B2C/AD).
Follow these steps present in these Microsoft documentations:

1. [Integrate web app to Azure AD B2C](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2)
2. As you said, the application crashes and trying to obtain authenticationResult, make sure these [settings configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0) correctly in order to get rid of that error.